# Spring boot Resttemplate HTTP POST with basic authentication and Custom Object

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http-headers

I have a spring boot REST service which I would like to do an HTTP POST call on with the following:
1- Basic Authentication
2- Send as a body my Object.

any help is much appreciated

**My code so far**

```
public String envoyer(SMS sms) {
        logger.info("Envoie SMS au serveur samba sur {} : {} : {}", properties.getUser(), properties.getPassword(), properties.getUrl());
        logger.info("SMS : {}", sms.toString());
        HttpEntity<String> request = getRequest(sms);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(properties.getUrl(), sms, String.class);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }

    private String getBase64Credentials(){
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        String creds = properties.getUser()+":"+properties.getPassword();
        byte[] credBytes = creds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64Bytes = encoder.encode(credBytes);
        logger.info("Credentials === "+creds);
        logger.info("Credentials Bytes === "+new String(credBytes));
        logger.info("Encoded Credentials === "+new String(base64Bytes));
        return new String(base64Bytes);
    }

    private HttpEntity getRequest(SMS sms){

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + getBase64Credentials());
        headers.add("sms", sms.toString());
        return new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    }
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: see the edit.. @DanielSquires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

Instead of using HttpEntity, one should use [RequestEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/RequestEntity.html#RequestEntity-T-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-java.net.URI-)

RequestEntity req = new RequestEntity(smsString, headers, HttpMethod.POST,URI.create(url) , String.class);